# How get Data form wordpress database as array not stdclass?

Tags: database

Guys I tried this code:

```
$wpdb->get_results(sprintf("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = '%s' AND post_type = 'edd_payment'",$id));
```

it returned an std class How can I get data form db as array not stdclass?

Comment: Any reason your using mySQL instead of Wordpress core functions to pull data?

Comment: you can have this result with this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here
[$wpdb->get_results](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)

`$wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A );`